# How to extract List and Map in json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I'm new in Scala and do not know how to deal with this Json with json4s:

After parsing the json and extracting the following json through:

```
val data = json \\ "someKey"
```

I have a Json like this:

```
[{"Id":14706061,
   "Rcvr":1,
    "HasSig":true,
    "Sig":80},
 {"Id":3425490,
  "Rcvr":1,
  "HasSig":false,
  "Sig": 80}]
```

Printing it to the console, it returns:

```
JArray(List(JObject(List((Id,JInt(14706061)), (Rcvr,JInt(1)), (HasSig,JBool(true)), (Sig,JInt(80), Id,JInt(3425490)), (Rcvr,JInt(1)), (HasSig,JBool(false)), (Sig,JInt(80) ))
```

So, after that I used:

```
println("show values: " + data.values)
```

And had:

```
List(Map(Id -> 14706061, Rcvr -> 1, HasSig -> true, Sig -> 80), Map(Id -> 3425490, Rcvr -> 1, HasSig -> false, Sig -> 80))
```

But I don't know how to extract each Map from each position of the List.

I also tried to extract to a case class but I had 0 entries:

```
case class Example (Id: BigInt, Rcvr: Int, HasSig: Boolean, Sig: Int)

case class ExampleList (examples: List[Example])

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats.strict

val dataList = data.extract[ExampleList]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

PD. If I assign:

```
val dataList = data.values
```

The type of dataList (with getClass) is: class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

### PD2. SOLUTION

After the:

```
 val data = json \\ "someKey"
```

I put:

`val dataList = data.extract[JArray]`
`val examples = dataList.values`

It returns an iterable Array with its Maps iterable, so fixed.

Checked with:

`println("number of elements: " + examples.length)`

and

`println("show each item: " + examples.foreach(println))`

Thanks for taking your time in reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract into a Case Class instead of a Map, the correct type for extraction is `List[Example]`, instead of `ExampleList`.

`ExampleList` has an attribute `examples`, your json doesn't. That is why you got an empty list.

```
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s._

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val str = """[{"Id":14706061,
             "Rcvr":1,
              "HasSig":true,
              "Sig":80},
           {"Id":3425490,
            "Rcvr":1,
            "HasSig":false,
            "Sig": 80}]"""


case class Example (Id: BigInt, Rcvr: Int, HasSig: Boolean, Sig: Int)

val json = parse(str)

val examples = json.extract[List[Example]]
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for your help. I already fixed my problem with other strategy that fitted better with the data workflow, but anyway your contribution is perfect and simple.

Comment: hi, how can extract this?{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "apple",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "value": "5"
        }]}

Comment: @noors you need a case class that contains a list of items. eg, case class Container(List<Item> items), case class Item(name:String, value:String), json.extract[Container]

Comment: @SebastianCelestino I have entities Container(items: Seq[Item]) &
  Item(name: String, value: String). And when I do org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.parse(jsonString).extractOpt[Container] it returns - Some(Container(List())) even if jsonString is completely another structure than Container. What I need is to get None if json string is other thant Container, eg some error

Comment: I could search for field items ,e.g parse(jsonString) \ "items" and thus validate it's Container, but that looks like not the best aproach for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code helps.

```
enter code here

val iList = List(Map("Id" -> 14706061, "Rcvr" -> 1, "HasSig" -> "true", "Sig" -> 80), 
Map("Id" -> 3425490, "Rcvr" -> 1, "HasSig" -> false, "Sig" -> 80))

for(i <-0 until iList.size){val lMap = iList(i)println("Id: " + lMap("Id"))}
```

Comment: Thanks nanda, but the problem is that even if i assign data.values to a val, the type is not a List. e.g: val dataList = data.values.  dataList.getClass returns: class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

Comment: `scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon` is one of the classes used to create Lists, eg 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil == List(1,2,3)